# What happens when an object is only defined?

Tags: java, class, object, memory

I was wondering what happens at memory level when an object in defined, but not initialized.

For example:

```
public class MainClass {
 public static void main (String[] args){
  Object foo;
 }
}
```

Is *foo* pointing to a memory space?
Does this behaviour change between different programming languages?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know the object will point to *null* when used, but I am interested to know what happens just after the object has been defined, and not instantiated yet.
Is there a reference to the memory in this case?

Comment: There's just a variable here. No object.

Comment: In java, you simply got a reference to "nothing". No object. However, in C++ for example, you get a real object in this case. This in order to answer the second part of your question.

Comment: Variables inside a method without any modifiers are created on the stack.

Comment: To summarize a little: In Java, if `Object foo;` is used as a member, it will be initialized to `null`. If used in a method, you have to initialize `foo` by yourself, in my tests it was possible to run the code otherwise. C++ handles stuff a little differently. Here, `Object foo;` will cause the default constructor to be called, no matter where it's placed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering what happens at memory level when an object in defined, but not initialized.

Lets assume that we are talking about Java here.

First I must correct your incorrect description.  (For reasons that will become apparent ...)

This is not *defining an object*.  Rather, it is *declaring a variable*.  The identifier `foo` denotes a *variable*.  Since the type of the variable is (in this case) `Object` which is a reference type, the variable may contain either a reference to a Java object **or** `null`.

> Is `foo` pointing to a memory space?

The answer is slightly complicated.

- If the variable is initialized, it will either point to some object or it will contain `null`.
- If the variable is NOT initialized, then it depends on what type of variablle we are talking about:

  - For a field of a class (static or instance), a variable that is not explicitly initialized is *default initialized* to `null`.
  - For a variable that is a parameter or a catch variable, the Java language semantics ensure that the variable is always initialized ... so this is moot.
  - For a local variable, the JLS doesn't say what it contains before a value is assigned to it.  You could say that the value is indeterminate.  **However** the JLS (and at runtime, the JVM's classfile verifier) ensure that a program cannot use a local variable that is in an indeterminate state.  (It is a compilation error in Java code to read a variable that has not been *definitely assigned*.)  So it really makes no difference what the variable *actually* contains.

Note that in pure Java<sup>1</sup> it is not possible to access a variable that contains a value that it wasn't set by either assignment or initialization.  The Java Language Specification doesn't allow it and neither does the JVM Specification.  A variable can never be observed to contain a random memory address.

> Does this behavior change between different programming languages?

Err ... yes.  For example, in C and C++, a program may use the value of a pointer variable that has not been initialized.  The behavior that ensues is *unspecified*.

---

<sup>1 - If you use native code or `Unsafe`, it is possible for the code to corrupt a variable to contain anything.  But don't do this deliberately as this is liable to hard crash the JVM.  Native code and `Unsafe` means not pure Java.</sup>

Comment: As you already said, in Java objects are more like references. As also stated, the Java objects are best described with pointers in C++. But to add to completeness, you don't have to create a pointer in C++. By only stating `Object foo;`, C++ will call the default constructor.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle - I have not tried to explain all the differences between C or C++ declarations and Java.  That would be a different question (and Too Broad!).

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can think of object variables as pointers. By default they point to nothing, only the pointer itself is allocated (e.g. 8 bytes on the stack).

You can have it point to an actual instance of an object by allocating that object and assigning to the variable:

```
Object foo; // points to nothing (and may not be used)

foo.toString(); // compile error: The local variable obj may not have been initialized

foo = new Object(); // points to an instance of a new Object

foo = null; // again points to nothing, but is now initialized

foo.toString(); // will compile, but throw NullPointerException at run time
```

This is fundamentally different from C or C++, where `Object foo;` would actually be a local object allocated on the stack. Java never allocates objects on the stack, only primitive types or pointers.

Answer (score 2):

In java , foo will point to "null" when it define in class ,
and foo will point to nothing where it define in function .